# Try to add a row of emojis to discord server using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I can add an emoji to a discord server by this code
but how can i add a row of emojis at once to this discord server?

```js
         const emoticon = require('discord.js').Util.parseEmoji("EMOJI");

         if(emoticon.id == null) return message.channel.send('I could not find this emoji!');
         if(message.guild.emojis.cache.has(emoticon.id)) return message.reply("That emoji is already on the server")

         const emoji = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${emoticon.id}.${emoticon.animated  ? 'gif' : 'png'}`

         try {
         message.guild.emojis.create(emoji, emoticon.name || 'Emoji')

         await message.reply(`Successfully added \`${emoticon.name}\` emoji to this server!`)
         }catch(error){
           return message.channel.send(`An error has occurred ${error}`)
```

like what if this EMOJI is EMOJI_1 EMOJI_2 EMOJI_3

Comment: This can be done easily by inserting emojis' data into an array then loop through each element in it

Answer (score 0):

As ACGaming said, you can do it by creating an array and looping through it:

```
const emojiArray = ["EMOJI_1", "EMOJI_2", "EMOJI_3"];

emojiArray.forEach(emoji => {
  
  try {
    message.guild.emojis.create(emoji, emoticon.name || 'Emoji');

    await message.reply(`Successfully added \`${emoticon.name}\` emoji to this server!`);
  }catch(error){ 
    return message.channel.send(`An error has occurred ${error}`);
   }
    }
  )}
```